# trim display content in label

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I need to display additional text in tooltip as ellipse.

I'm using DevExpressDataView.

In design:

```
`<asp:Label ID="ModelDescLabel" runat="server" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;" Text='<%# Eval("Desc")%>' Font-Bold="False" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Desc")%>' >`
```

This will show tool tip irrespective of the length of the text and for all the cells.
So I need to write the logic in a event so as to show the tooltip only if it crosses the limit. Since I'm using DEVExpressDataView what is the equivalent of OnHtmlRowCreated as AspxDataview doesn't have any such event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DesignPage

```
<asp:Label ID="ModelDescLabel" runat="server" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;"  OnInit="ModelDescLabel_Init" >
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void ModelDescLabel_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxLabel label = (ASPxLabel)sender;
    DataViewItemTemplateContainer c = (DataViewItemTemplateContainer)label.NamingContainer;
    string categoryDesc = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "CategoryDesc").ToString();
    if (categoryDesc.Length != 0 || categoryDesc.Length != null)
    {
         if (categoryDesc.Length > 260)
         {
            label.Text = categoryDesc.Trim().Substring(0, 240) + "...";
            label.ToolTip = categoryDesc.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "");;
         }
         else
           label.Text = categoryDesc;
    }
}
```